# Why is the input that maximally activates a sparse autoencoder hidden unit of the following form?

Tags: neural-networks, autoencoders

[This source](http://deeplearning.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php?title=Visualizing_a_Trained_Autoencoder&oldid=2271) on feature visualization asserts that the input vector $X$, such that $\|X\|_2 \leq 1$, which maximally activates a sparse autoencoder's $i$th hidden unit is of the form
$$X_j = \frac{W^{(1)}_{ij}}{\sqrt{\sum_{j=1} (W^{(1)}_{ij})^2}},$$
where $W^{(1)}_{i}$ are the weights that the $i$th hidden unit depends on. It is assumed that the hidden units are using sigmoid activation functions.

Now obviously the denominator is simply making sure the norm of $X$ is less than or equal to $1$. Also, as the weights can be positive or negative, keeping the inputs the same sign as the weights will result in higher activation values.

After this, however, I am stuck. The source says it is not too hard to prove this, but I can't seem to find a way. An acceptable answer will most likely contain a formal proof, but some helpful intuition may also do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The activation of the hidden unit is given by $f(w \cdot x)$, where $f$ is a sigmoidal activation function, $w$ is the weight vector, and $x$ is a vector of inputs to the hidden unit. The problem is to find the input $x^*$ that maximally activates the hidden unit:

$$x^* = \underset{x}{\text{argmax }} f(w \cdot x) \quad s.t. \|x\| \le 1$$

The activation function is monotonic, so it doesn't affect the answer and we can ignore it. This is because any $x$ that maximizes $w \cdot x$ will also maximize $f(w \cdot x)$. The problem becomes:

$$x^* = \underset{x}{\text{argmax }} w \cdot x \quad s.t. \|x\| \le 1$$

There are a couple ways to proceed from here. One way would be to analytically solve the optimization problem, which would be pretty straightforward. Another is to use geometric intuition about the dot product. We can write the dot product as:

$$w \cdot x = \|w\| \|x\| \cos \theta$$

where $\theta$ is the angle between $w$ and $x$. This expression tells us that, when $w$ and $x$ have given magnitudes, the dot product will be maximized when the angle is zero. This means that the optimal input will be a scaled version of $w$. The expression also tells us that, for a given $\theta$ and magnitude of $w$, the dot product will increase with $\|x\|$. The constraint on the optimization problem only allows $\|x\|$ to take a maximum value of 1. Therefore, the optimal input (subject to the constraint) is a normalized version of the weights:

$$x^* = \frac{w}{\|w\|}$$

**Edit:** How to solve the optimization problem

$$x^* = \underset{x}{\text{argmax }} w \cdot x \quad s.t. \|x\| \le 1$$

Write out the [KKT conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KKT_conditions) for this problem. In this case, they're sufficient for optimality. At an optimal solution $x^*$, there must exist a constant $\lambda$ such that the following conditions hold:

- Stationarity: $w = \lambda \frac{x^*}{\|x^* \|}$ (obtained by taking the gradient of the objective and constraint functions).
- Primal feasibility: $\|x^*\| \le 1$
- Dual feasibility: $\lambda \ge 0$
- Complementary slackness: $\lambda (\|x^*\| - 1) = 0$

The complementary slackness condition says that at least one of the following must be true: a) $\lambda = 0$ or b) $\|x^*\| = 1$. (a) can't be true because it would violate the stationarity condition (assuming $w$ isn't the zero vector, which would make all inputs equivalent and the problem pointless). Therefore, $\|x^*\| = 1$ (which also satisfies the primal feasibility condition).

The stationarity condition then simplifies to: $x^* = \frac{w}{\lambda}$

This means $x^*$ is a scaled version of $w$. The only values of $\lambda$ that satisfy this condition and the requirement that $\|x^*\|=1$ are a) $\lambda = \|w\|$ and b) $\lambda = -\|w\|$. The dual feasbility condition says that (b) can't be true.

Therefore, $\lambda = \|w\|$ and $x^* = \frac{w}{\|w\|}$, which uniquely satisfies all conditions.

Comment: I think the geometric intuition is clever, but how would one solve this analytically? Specifically, solving for the argmax with our given constraint seems like it could yield any number of forms, and not necessarily the one we are trying to prove.

Comment: I think the geometric picture implies a unique solution, but I edited the post to include solving the optimization problem directly, which yields the same result

Comment: This should hold for any network with this type of activation function, not just sparse autoencoders. The solution is unique because the activation is a strictly monotonic function of the dot product. If the activation function had a hard upper saturation point, for example, there could be (uncountably) many solutions.